# Use of logical operators for recoding variables

Tags: r

I'm currently creating a dummy variable to check for eligibility for data analysis. I want to create an additional factor variable to indicate the reason for ineligibility. But, when using the same logical operators for both variables, I can't seem to get matching results.

The first variable is the dummy:

```
data$elig <- factor(1, 1:2, labels = c("yes", "no"))
```

I first set all rows to `yes`, then recode ineligible rows with

```
data$elig[data$var1 == 20 | data$var2 > 1998 | 
          (data$var2 == 1998 & as.numeric(data$var3) > 9) |
            (data$var2 == 1998 & is.na(data$var3)) | is.na(data$var4) | 
             is.na(data$var5) | is.na(data$var6)] <- "no"
```

This gives me the following results for `data$elig`:

```
table(data$elig)
yes   no 
2707  170
```

Now I create the second variable with some nested `ifelses` (btw, is there a simpler solution to do this?):

```
data$elig_cat <- ifelse(data$var1 == 20, 1, 
                  ifelse(data$var2 > 1998 | 
                           (data$var2 == 1998 & as.numeric(data$var3) > 9) | 
                           (data$var2 == 1998 & is.na(data$var3)), 2, 
                   ifelse(is.na(data$var2), 3, 
                    ifelse(is.na(data$var4), 4, 
                      ifelse(is.na(data$var5), 5, 
                        ifelse(is.na(data$var6), 6, NA))))))
```

But `table(data$elig_cat)` only has 117 valid counts:

```
 1  2  4  5 
75 22  9 11
```

My question is: Do I make a simple mistake anywhere (though I've looked for everything I could think of), or is this a problem of my approach? From my understanding, the second table should have 170 valid counts, as each logical operator used led to a `no`-count in the first variable.

If necessary, I can provide the data, but I think only the full dataset would make any sense. Maybe someone can point me to any irregularity I could look for in the data? I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: Have you considered [this](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16417) `ifelse` behaviour?

Comment: Leo, could you upload some representative data?

Comment: Thanks @count, I did not about that behaviour. Got to try it with single operations then. I will upload some data tomorrow.